# Cognos - Date variables for many queries

Tags: variables, filter, cognos

I'm using Bullhorn Canvas which runs on Cognos.  I'm looking for the simplest way to have query filters based on a prompt with this dropdown:
THIS WEEK
LAST WEEK
THIS MONTH
LAST MONTH
THIS QUARTER
LAST QUARTER
YEAR TO DATE

The report requires many queries with date filters. As far as I can see, I have to write filters in each query that look like this:

[StartDate] between
(case ?Dates Dropdown?
when 'THISWEEK' then _add_days(current_date, -_day_of_week(current_date, 1) + 1)
when 'LASTWEEK' then _add_days(current_date, -_day_of_week(current_date, 1) - 6)
when 'THISMONTH' then _first_of_month(current_date)
end)
and
(case ?Dates Dropdown?
when 'THISWEEK' then _add_days(current_date, -_day_of_week(current_date,1) + 7)
when 'LASTWEEK' then _add_days(current_date, -_day_of_week(current_date,1))
when 'THISMONTH' then _last_of_month(current_date)
when 'LASTMONTH' then _last_of_month(_add_months(current_date, -1))
end)

This is actually shortened. The real filter will be even bigger than this.

As far as I can see, I have to repeat this monstrous filter in every query, and I'd like to avoid that.  In other programming languages, I'd create two variables, for example Date1 and Date2.  I'd calculate those variables once, based on the dropdown.  Then each query would simply say [StartDate] between [Date1] and [Date2].

Is there a way to do this in Cognos?

Comment: Do you have framework manager?  Might have a slick solution for you

Comment: I don't have Framework Manager. I'm doing a project for a client who has recruiting software Bullhorn Canvas, which is based on Cognos. The client does not have Framework Manager.

Comment: Do you have a table that represents time, i.e. Year, Quarter, Month?
If so, you could join to it.  The inner join would act as a filter.
Let me know if you have something like this, or maybe your DBA could create one.  IF so, I might have a solution you would like

Comment: I don't have a table for time periods, but perhaps I can make one on the fly in a query whenever the report is run in Bullhorn. Does that fit into the solution you have in mind?

Comment: Was thinking a bit more, may have an easier solution.  Drop down This week gives a from and to date for all the queries (i.e.  1/2 to 1/6) .   If we picked this month maybe the from and to date would be 1/1 to 1/31.   As long as you get a from and to date as parameters would that meet the requirement?

Comment: Yes, getting a from and to date as parameters is exactly what I want. I don't know how to get parameters from a dropdown. How would I do that?

Comment: Okay I gave an answer below, there are many ways to do what you want.  Let me know what you think or if you have questions

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, we can use the value prompt with static values to set the ranges and then use a join to have the query (or multiple queries) filter based on that range

Step 1 create a value prompt with static values like this:
[image]

Step 2 create a query that will have the data items for the ranges like this:
[image]

Each data item has the case statement like you gave above

For example, this would be for the data item FromRange

[image]

Step 3 navigate to where you can see all of your queries.  From the insertable objects, using a join you will have your query follow the from and to range like this:
[image]

The join would look like this (note towards the bottom for the operator we use >= for FROM):
[image]

and this for the range (and the <= for the TO):
[image]

Remember in the Query from the join you just need to re-add the data items you want to show in your content

Comment: Thank you, that may work. The only problem is that my report is built up from 9 queries.  Each query needs its own date range filter. Then there are a series of joins that put the 9 queries together, one by one, until I have my final monster report. With your solution, I'd have to add 10 new queries: "Query For Ranges" and 9 new join queries to join each of my queries with "Query For Ranges". It's complicated, but it may be the best solution.

Comment: I think you might have lucked out.    You would just add the one query and keep carrying the answer over for filtering purposes.  Also, there may be another solution you may like, there is more than one way to do this, I was just sharing what might be the easiest.  Let me draft something and get back to you